# Admob Banner is not being displayed in front of my activity

Tags: android, xml, admob

I've added the add mob banner to my activity and it is working as it should. Just one thing is wrong that it isnt being displayed in front instead it is displayed in background. I wish to bring it to front but im unable to do so.

Here is my XML file:

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    app:umanoClipPanel="false"
    app:umanoOverlay="true"
    app:umanoPanelHeight="@dimen/sliding_panel_height"
    app:umanoShadowHeight="4dp"
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:addStatesFromChildren="true"
                android:visibility="visible"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
            android:id="@+id/wallpaper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|start"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:padding="@dimen/content_margin"
            android:theme="@style/RippleStyleLight" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_panel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#66000000"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/top_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/sliding_panel_height"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/content_padding"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/content_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/content_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/content_margin"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/content_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/content_padding">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    fontPath="fonts/Font-Medium.ttf"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_content_title" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/author"
                    fontPath="fonts/Font-Regular.ttf"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_content" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/menu_preview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:padding="@dimen/content_margin"
                android:theme="@style/RippleStyle" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/menu_save"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:padding="@dimen/content_margin"
                android:theme="@style/RippleStyle"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/menu_apply"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:padding="@dimen/content_margin"
                android:theme="@style/RippleStyle" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/top_bar"
            android:clipToPadding="false" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

It doesn't matter where I place the `AdView`, it always gets displayed at back instead of front.

[Problem description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zru97.jpg)

I'm trying to add admbob banner on that closing wallpaper screen.

I have added banner in front of acivity ie
[I am trying to add banner at the bottom of the wallpaper.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8OYe.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

**This code show how to display banner in activity. it is worked for me**

**XML code**

```
  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_home_footer"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**This code add in manifest file**

```
<manifest>
<application>
    <!-- AdMob App ID: ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="[ADMOB_APP_ID]"/>
</application>
```

**This code add in Java file **

```
private AdView mAdView;
// Advertisement function calling...
 private void setupAdvertisement() {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            // Check the LogCat to get your test device ID
            .addTestDevice("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
            .build();

    mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            Debug.d("setupAdvertisement", "onAdLoaded");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            Debug.d("setupAdvertisement", "onAdClosed");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            Debug.d("setupAdvertisement", "onAdFailedToLoad " + errorCode);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLeftApplication() {
            Debug.d("setupAdvertisement", "onAdLeftApplication ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
            Debug.d("setupAdvertisement", "onAdOpened ");
        }
    });

    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

}
```